# Fast reading files Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote script which animate some values from files. Here is code [line graph from loop in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883482/line-graph-from-loop-in-python)

But to the folder write every second 10 files (size of one file 3MB) and for 30 second I dont have actual graph. I think that the problem will be in sorted function and then i for loop.

My question is: Can I create some buffer which will be buffering last n(300) files? Or exist some fast metod for for-loop?

Thanks

Comment: 30MB/s... how much can your disk handle?

Comment: I have raptor disk (10000 rpm) with 180 MB/s write..This is not problem

Comment: Use one of the [profilers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to determine, what function actually takes most of the time.

Comment: Ok I used some profilers and seem that problem is really in for-loop for image_list and in finding data max.